# About two ways of computing the probability of an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let us say that we have coin which shows heads with probability $0.002$ and we want to know the probability of getting 1 head in 1000 tosses. The "standard" way to count this is to compute $(1000)(0.002)(0.998)^{999}$.

Is there a way to count this number using a more basic principle of evaluating, $\frac{\# \text{of desired events}  }{ \# \text{total number of possible events }}$ ?

Comment: There  isn't. But there is for a related problem. We have $500$ coins in a box, $1$ two-headed, and the other $499$ two-tailed. We choose a coin at random, flip, record the result, replace. Do this $1000$ times. Then the probability of exactly $1$ head can be found by counting.

Answer (score 1):

> Let us say that we have coin which shows heads with probability $0.002$ and we want to know the probability of getting 1 head in 1000 tosses. The "standard" way to count this is to compute $(1000)(0.002)(0.998)^{999}$.
>
> Is there a way to count this number using a more basic principle of evaluating, $\frac{\# \text{of desired events}  }{ \# \text{total number of possible events }}$ ?

Yes*sish*.   The "more basic principle" only works when you have *equally probable* outcomes.

- So we *could* model the biased coin as having $1000$ equally-likely outcomes, two of which are called heads and nine-hundred ninety-eight of which are called tails.   (Keywords: microstate, macrostate.)

  The count of ways to make $1000$ independent choices each with $1000$ equally probable options is $1000^{1000}$.

  The count of ways to make $1$ choice with $2$ equally likely option is $2^1$.   The count of ways to make $999$ independent choices with $998$ equally probable options is $998^{999}$.   The count of ways to select $1$ place among $1000$ is ${^{1000}{\rm C}_{1}}$.

  Putting this together we have: $$\begin{align}\dfrac{\# \text{of desired events} }{ \# \text{total number of possible events }}~=&~\dfrac{{^{1000}{\rm C}_{1}}\cdot 2^1\cdot 998^{999} }{1000^{1000}}
  \\[1ex] = & ~ 1000~(0.002)~(0.998)^{999}
  \end{align}$$
- We *don't* do this because modeling the bias of a coin in such a ways is a naive kludge.   We simply observe that the coin has two visible outcomes with different *probability weights*.   Then we simply measure the probability of heads on one coin and tails on $998$, appearing in any of the $^{1000}{\rm C}_1$ ways to arrange these results, as: $${^{1000}{\rm C}_{1}}~(0.002)~(0.998)^{999}$$